# How can I get vim autocompletion working in iTerm

Tags: macos, vim, terminal, autocomplete, iterm

I recently switched from MacVim to regular Vim in iTerm. I've been encountering an issue where I can't get vim's autocompletion to trigger using <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd>.

Instead, I get iTerm's autocompletion which autocompletes differently than Vim's.

[image: iTerm's Autocomplete]
[image: Vim's autocomplete]

I've tried going into the iTerm preferences and remapping <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> to ignore. I'm not sure if that's just preventing that input from reaching Vim but it does disable the iTerm autocompletion.

Comment: The default shortcut for iTerm's completion is `Cmd-;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I had set a shortcut setting in System Preferences that had overridden that key a long time ago and forgot about it. That's what was causing the issue.